# Encuentran algún error en el código PHP

Tags: php

**¿Existe algun error en el siguiente código?**

Este código corresponde al archivo php que crea una nueva entrada en mi base de datos mysql, el cual en la parte frontend está realizada con
angular.js pero no guarda en la base de datos la nueva entrada, por lo
que necesito saber si ustedes ven algún error en el código por favor.

```
<?php
// Incluir la clase de base de datos
include_once("../classes/class.Database.php");

$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); 

$request = json_decode($postdata);
$request =  (array) $request;


$request['marca'] = strtoupper($request['marca']);


$sql = "INSERT INTO autos(marca, modelo, color, ano, precio,)
        VALUES ('".$request['marca']."',
                '".$request['modelo']."',
                '".$request['color']."', 
                '".$request['ano']."', 
                '".$request['precio']."' )";


$Hecho = Database::ejecutar_idu($sql);
$Respuesta = "";

if ($Hecho == "1") {
    $Respuesta = json_encode( array('err' => false, 'mensaje'=>'Registro Insertado.' ));
}else{
    $Respuesta = json_encode( array('err' => true, 'mensaje'=> $Hecho ));
}

echo $Respuesta;

?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. No sé php, creí que la pregunta era relacionada con angular.js como dice en el título y por eso estoy aquí. Lo único que puedo decir es que el código es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL.

Comment: ¿No obtienes ningún tipo de error? ¿ En el error log tampoco ? Si no recibes ningún error, has probado a usar var_dump o print_r con las variables para ir viendo su valor mientras se va ejecutando el código y ver si dichas variables corresponden con lo que esperas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay una coma extra al final del listado de columnas:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO autos(marca, modelo, color, ano, precio,)
```

Esa línea debe ser

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO autos(marca, modelo, color, ano, precio)
```

Comment: estabas en lo correcto, por eso no me insertaba en la base de datos. muchas gracias